# Parse array in jquery from ajax request

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

I am having the hardest time parsing the response from an ajax request correctly.
I have an ajax request that gets back a json array, all I need to do is parse it correctly so I get my two values out.

On the php side, I create the array like so:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $response[]=array("value" => $row["uid"], "text" => $row["value"]);
        }
```

My array in PHP looks like this when I print_r:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [value] => 6 [text] => 40 ) [1] => Array ( [value] => 7 [text] => 48 ) )
```

I then json_encode that array and send it back via ajax.
Here is my ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'ajax.php?s='+selection,
                dataType: 'json',                        
                success: function (data) {
                        $.each( data, function( intValue, currentElement ) {
                                $.each(currentElement, function( key, value ) {
                                    console.log(key);
                                    console.log(value);
                                });
                        });

                }
        });
```

I would have thought console.log(key) would show 6 and console.log(value) would show 40 but instead I get:

```
value
6
text
40
value
7
text
48
```

I really need help just getting 6 and 40 then 7 and 48 (based on array provided).

I have tried a bunch of ways, nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using single **[`$.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** , and object property can access like **[`object.property`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** or **[`object\["property"\]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**

```js
var data = [{
  value: 6,
  text: 40
}, {
  value: 7,
  text: 48
}];
$.each(data, function(i, v) {
  document.write(v.value);
  document.write(v.text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I added to my question how I create my array, am I creating it wrong?

Comment: @Jason : I couldn't see anything wrong in that. You can use single `$.each` to iterate

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
 $.ajax({
                    url: URL,
                    dataType: "text",
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    success: function (data2) {

                        json_obj2 = $.parseJSON(data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `each` loop that isn't needed

Your javascript data looks like:

```
[{"value" : 6, "text" : 40}, {"value" : 7, "text" : 48}]
```

So in first `each` loop `intVal` will be index of array and `currentElement` will be each object instance in the array

The object instance looks like:

```
{"value" : 6, "text" : 40}
```

So `currentElement.value` and `currentElement.text` are what you are looking for

```
$.each( data, function( intValue, currentElement ) {
      console.log(currentElement.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, change the php side to be:

```
$response[$row["uid"]] = $row["value"]
```